# JQuery how to increment date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two input fields, one with a start date and one with the finish date. How can i automaticaly setup the finish date as start date + 1 day when i input a date in the first field?
My code is like this:

```
<form>
Start: <input type="text" name="date_start" id="datepicker0">
Stop: <input type="text" name="date_stop" id="datepicker1">
</form>
```

Comment: My guess is using the [`onSelect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) handler, you'll need to [`getDate()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) from the first, increment one day, then call [`setDate()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) on the second.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUi's DatePicker?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't hear anything back, but apparently somebody took care of that.

Answer (score 11):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ffwr2/1/

```
$('#date1').datepicker();
$('#date2').datepicker();

$('#date1').change(function(){
    var date1 = $('#date1').datepicker('getDate');
    var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
    date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );

    var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
    newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );

    $('#date2').datepicker('setDate', newDate );
})
```

Comment: Should probably add the same handler to the `paste` and `keyup` events, since `change` will only trigger on losing focus (if the value has changed of course).

Comment: Following @liho1eye's comment, if you do, put it in a function and call each from the respective handlers.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this :) ... Let me just note that there is no need to use global variables (initiated using "var") in this context.